# How to access title attribute in <div> tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to access the title attribute in a  tag of a website. But for some reason this piece of code gives me an error:

```
html_data=requests.get("https://www.olx.com.pk/items/q-white-bantam").content
html_data=BeautifulSoup(html_data, "lxml")

ads=html_data.find_all("li", {"aria-label":"Listing"})[0]
ads=ads.find_all("a")
tag=ads.find("div")["title"]
print(tag)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

There are different issues in your code:

- You should iterate your `ResultSet` to use `find()` on every element to avoid:

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're
> probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you
> call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

- There is no `<div>` with attribut `title` it is in the `<a>`:

  ```
  <a href="/item/black-and-white-bantam-for-sale-iid-1048730374" title="Black and White bantam for Sale"><div class="_193d9c7f"></div></a>
  ```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_data=requests.get("https://www.olx.com.pk/items/q-white-bantam").content
html_data=BeautifulSoup(html_data, "lxml")

for ad in html_data.find_all("li", {"aria-label":"Listing"}):
    print(ad.a.get('title'))
    
    ### or longform
    ### print(ad.find('a').get('title'))
```

###### Output

```
Silk Bantam Cochin Blue columbian Brahma white Aseel Blue motled bantm
Black and White bantam for Sale
Black Bantam White Bantam bentum
White Bantam chicks for sale
...
```